# How to create an iterator based on another collection

Tags: c#

I have a collection of Users List where User looks like:
User
-id
-uniqueKey (String)

I have another collection of List where ExternalUser has a uniqueKey also.

I want to loop through the List, but actually return a External User.

How can I create an iterator that does this?

Comment: This looks like an XY problem. Why do you think you need an iterator? Can't you use projection (`.Select()`)? Can you show some example input, some code and some example output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without having your sample code, it is hard to fully answer. However, this is a code sample that I believe would provide you with what you are looking for:

```
var externalUsers = users.Select(user => externalUserIds.Contains(user.UniqueKey));
```

That will provide you with a iterator of user object instances which have a UniqueKey of an external user.